# .Net Entity Framework Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is a piece of my DB, creaated according to code first principle:
I have an abstract class Client (a table of this class is created in my data base):

```
    public abstract class Client
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required for Client")]
        public string ClientName { get; set; } // name

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required for Client")]
        public string ClientPhoneNumber { get; set; } // phone number

        public string Email { get; set; } // email

        public string Comment { get; set; } // note

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Client should be enabled or disabled")]
        public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    }
```

Three classes are inherited from it:

1)

```
    public class PrivatePerson : Client // дядя Вася
    {
        public string PrivatePersonSurname { get; set; }
    }
```

2)

```
    public class Firm : Client
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ownership is required for Firm")]
        public virtual Ownership Ownership { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Client address is required for Firm")]
        public virtual ClientAddress FirmAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

3)

```
    public class AdvertisingAgency : Client
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ownership is required for Advertising agency")]
        public virtual Ownership Ownership { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Client address is required for Advertising agency")]
        public virtual ClientAddress AdvertisingAgencyAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

!! Firm and AdvertisingAgency have similar fields

And here is ClientAddress class:

```
    public class ClientAddress
    {
        public int ClientAddressId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postal code is required for Client Address")]
        public int PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required for Client Address")]
        public virtual City ClientCity { get; set; }

        public int POBox { get; set; }

        public virtual Street ClientStreet { get; set; }

        public string StreetNumber { get; set; }

        public int Appartment { get; set; }

        public string ClientAddressComment { get; set; }
    }
```

Context:

```
public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<ClientAddress> ClientAddresses { get; set; }
```

Well, when i'm trying to create a DB, I get this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>     HResult=0x80131904
>     Message=Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Clients_dbo.ClientAddresses_FirmAddress_ClientAddressId' on table 'Clients' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Can anyone, please, point out my mistake?
Thanks

This is my context (partly) :

```
public class FivePlusDBContext : DbContext
{
    public FivePlusDBContext() : base("name = FivePlus")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Street> Streets { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ClientAddress> ClientAddresses { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Ownership> Ownerships { get; set; }
}
```

To create a record, i do the following:

```
    using (var ctx = new FivePlusDBContext())
        {
            City C_1 = new City() { CityName = "Name" };
            ctx.Cities.Add(C_1);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Would you share the Fluent Api codes too?

Comment: How does the `onModelCreating` method look like in yoru context? You could try the following: 
`protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
                .HasOne(c => c.ClientAddress)
                .WithOptional(a => a.Client)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
       }`

Comment: Edited my question to help you understand how i create DB. And when I'm trying to create any record, I get an Exception

Comment: I'm not using DbModelBuilder

Comment: Nope, Each unit (Firm or AdvertisingAgency) will have unique address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all be aware that EntityFramework by default creates just one table per hierarchy (see [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) for details). In that case a special column (Discriminator) gets added to the `Clients` table to distinguish between persistent classes.

Now to your question.

According your model I assume that you want to use the same `ClientAddress` for multiple clients of type `Firm` and `AdvertisingAgency`. As both classes `Firm` and `AdvertisingAgency` have a property of type `ClientAddress` EntityFramework will generate two foreign keys on Clients table that point to `ClientAddress` (`FK_dbo.Clients_dbo.ClientAddresses_AdvertisingAgencyAddress_ClientAddressId` and `FK_dbo.Clients_dbo.ClientAddresses_FirmAddress_ClientAddressId`). For both foreign keys EntityFramework enables cascading delete by default. This leads to the exception that this may cause multiple cascade paths.

There are multiple possibilities that could solve the problem.

- Create two different address types and refer to one of them in `Firm` and to the other one in `AdvertisingAgency` class (reusing addresses will not be possible anymore)
- Change strategy to `Table per Concrete class (TPC)` (see [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) could maybe also solve the problem (not tested)
- Disable cascading delete using Fluent API

To disable cascading delete add the following code to your Context class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Firm>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.FirmAddress)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<AdvertisingAgency>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.AdvertisingAgencyAddress)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Mention: this could lead to orphaned addresses. When deleting a client its address will not get deleted. However the address could still be related to another client. Furthermore deletion of an address will not be possible as long as the address is related to at least one client. If trying to delete an address that still relates to multiple clients the following exception will be thrown.

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Comment: Thanks alot, man. Tha's what i expected to hear. And this is so simple and obvious. But i stuck at some point and could not identify the mistake. Thanks again